# Thread state tracing

Tags: c#

how can i trace thread state if it is alive or not ?

what i want to do is to execute function by thread and while thread is working (running) another form is show then when thread finish executing function form closed .

so how can i make change event fired when thread is finished ?

something like this:

```
Thread a = new Thread(fun);
    a.Start();
    a.changed += DoWork;
        void DoWork(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        //work
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try
[BackgroundWorker](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
:

The example on the MSDN page is pretty similar to what you're trying to do.